# Code in header files seems to cause errors on compile

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, header-files

I have a CLI program consisting of a single vt.c file that compiles and runs under Windows (cmd.exe) using Open Watcom. I can also compile it for Linux while running Open Watcom on Windows (and the resulting build runs under linux).

When I try to compile it under linux however (using make, which calls cc), I get 375 lines of error messages. Here are some of them, where many subsequent errors were similar, I have only pasted the first few:

```
In file included from vt.c:4:0:
process.h: In function ‘__declspec’:
process.h:45:22: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘execl’
process.h:46:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘__declspec’
process.h:47:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘__declspec’
...
In file included from vt.c:5:0:
ctype.h:48:1: warning: empty declaration
ctype.h:81:37: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘__ctype_b_loc’
ctype.h:82:6: warning: ‘__nothrow__’ attribute ignored
ctype.h:83:28: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘__ctype_tolower_loc’
ctype.h:84:6: warning: ‘__nothrow__’ attribute ignored
ctype.h:85:28: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘__ctype_toupper_loc’
ctype.h:86:6: warning: ‘__nothrow__’ attribute ignored
...
In file included from vt.c:6:0:
string.h:44:14: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘memcpy’
string.h:46:6: warning: ‘__nothrow__’ attribute ignored
string.h:49:14: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘memmove’
string.h:50:6: warning: ‘__nothrow__’ attribute ignored
string.h:57:14: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘memccpy’
string.h:59:6: warning: ‘__nothrow__’ attribute ignored
...
vt.c:28:1: warning: empty declaration
vt.c:41:1: warning: empty declaration
vt.c:50:1: error: parameter ‘maxtextlength’ is initialized
vt.c:70:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
vt.c:123:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
vt.c:158:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
...
vt.c:67:6: error: declaration for parameter ‘clearinputbuffer’ but no such parameter
vt.c:66:6: error: declaration for parameter ‘clrscr’ but no such parameter
vt.c:65:6: error: declaration for parameter ‘testrandom’ but no such parameter
...
string.h:579:14: error: declaration for parameter ‘stpncpy’ but no such parameter
...
ctype.h:268:12: error: declaration for parameter ‘toupper_l’ but no such parameter
...
process.h:45:22: error: declaration for parameter ‘execl’ but no such parameter
vt.c:608:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
make: *** [vt] Error 1
```

My problem is, as (I'm sure) many have had before: I just want it to compile.

Question 3641178 seems to suggest that the order of the include files is important, but the headers that are giving errors come AFTER all other included files in vt.c.

I have tried installing Open Watcom on Linux, and the provided header files are the same. As far as I know, these are standard header files, and I can think of no reason why they should cause compile errors.

If anyone can shed any light on this, I'd be very grateful. The entire directory can be accessed in my git repo at git@github.com:megamasha/Vocab-Tester.git (https://github.com/megamasha/Vocab-Tester)

Comment: Are you sure that _WCRTLINK is defined?

Comment: @arke: No, I'm not at all sure if it's defined.
Alas my knowledge of C is still very limited at this point, and my knowledge of using it under linux even moreso.
Can you tell me how I can find out if it's defined, or how I can do about defining it?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's the reason you're using local headers for `process.h`, `ctype.h`, and `string.h`?

Comment: @stevehb: I've made them local and then uploaded them to the git repo in case anyone could find anything wrong with them - that way people could see if there actually was anything wrong with the headers rather than just having to assume that my headers were the same as whatever they were using. Until I posted this question, I was using standard headers from my system include directory.

Comment: Cool, an Indonesian speaker! On Linux, are you trying to compile with gcc or with Open Watcom? 'cc' normally points to gcc. If you want to use gcc, then the Git repository is missing ``_comdef.h`` -- given that you include some Open Watcom headers (e.g. ``process.h``)

Comment: In short: for debugging purposes if anyone needed to look that closely.

Comment: @hircus: Yeah, I originally wrote a similar program in Microsoft excel with basic macros to learn German vocab, but I wanted more control, and I wanted to learn C, so when I wanted to improve my Indonesian, I set about this project.
I'm using cc, which I assume probably points to gcc. I wasn't aware that you could include headers that would only work with one compiler (that seems silly to me). So for compiling with gcc, I need to include `_comdef.h`? I'll try that. Are there compiler flags I can use with `#ifdef` to only include that header if needed?

Comment: @M_M: no, `_comdef.h` is a Windows-only thing. Read my answer!

Comment: You can use ``-D`` to define the header guard, so that the header does not get sourced. But you'd probably want to find out which headers you need for compiling against GCC, and then specify which headers are sourced based on which compiler you're using

Comment: @hircus: Well thanks for all your help. It turns out it was process.h that was the problem. Commented it out and it's all compiling and hunky-dory. I have a sneaky suspicion  the inclusion of process.h was on the advice of a C tutorial at <cplus.about.com>... Oh well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `process.h`, `string.h`, ... come from a specific compiler (watcom) and contain compiler-specific keywords (e.g. `__declspec`) that are not supported by `gcc` (the compiler usually used on Linux).

As far as `string.h` and `ctype.h` are concerned, you should remove them completely from your directory and `#include` them with angular brackets (`<...>`): they are standard headers and each compiler provide its versions (that are compatible with what the standard says).

With `process.h`, the situation is a bit more difficult, since it's a nonstandard header. Still, as far as I see, `process.h` seems to contain just some functions that are used to spawn processes, and, from a quick look, it seems that your application doesn't need it; if so, just remove `process.h` and the relative `#include`. Otherwise, tell me in the comment, probably there's a quick standard (or OS-specific, but not compiler-specific) replacement.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I only need process.h for the system() function. I will be using ncurses (some more non-portable joy in store for me there no doubt) in the next version to get around using system().

Comment: `system` is a standard function, available into the header `<stdlib.h>`; use this header instead of `"process.h"` and you should be fine. Incidentally, a port of ncurses for Windows does exist, so you should get away with small or no modifications to run the code on both platforms.

Comment: Well thanks for all your help. It turns out it was process.h that was the problem. Commented it out and it's all compiling and hunky-dory. I have a sneaky suspicion the inclusion of process.h was on the advice of a C tutorial at <cplus.about.com>... You are my accepted answer :-)

Comment: OK, I retract that - everything is not quite so hunky-dory. Where previously, in the version compiled with open watcom on windows, the line `system("clear")` worked (it cleared the screen), in the cc-compiled version, I now get a segmentation fault and quit to the shell. I'm not sure if you can help me, or if I should open a new question on this one...

Comment: No, wait... I've commented out the clear screen command entirely, and I still get a segmentation fault. I'll have to look into this a little closer...

Comment: Probably there's some other issue, e.g. some dangling pointer or stuff like that, that works by chance on Windows but fails on Linux. You should create a new question about it.